# I'm not understanding the usage of C# get; set; seems to be different from Java

Tags: c#

I know there are a few questions on stack overflow on this already but I haven't found any that answer my specific question. I came from a java development background and never bothered using the get; set; methods from C# until now.

I have the following code

```
class Test
{
    public int test { get; set; }
}
```

In my main function I can declare a new Test and use `t.Test = 5` and that works fine; however, when I switch the `public` to `private` I cannot access my get; and set; methods anymore... BUT when I use (Similar method to Java)

```
class Test
{
    private int test;

    public int getTest()
    {
        return this.test;
    }

    public void setTest(int test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

I'm confused on the design philosophy. In C# should I no longer be using private variables (Only make it private if it's used internally in the class) and make them all public and use private get; private set; to control accessibility?

Comment: because you made it private and its only accessible within that class, not from outside class

Comment: Switch your getTest and setTest to private and you won't be able to access your methods anymore... Magic!

Comment: Well, I get that but isn't that what the get and set methods supposed to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write this (I'm using different class and property names for clarity):

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

that's asking the compiler to create a private *field* with a public *property*. It's equivalent to:

```
public class Test
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

(Except the field name is autogenerated and not directly representable in C#.)

That's basically equivalent to what you'd write in Java as:

```
// Java
public class Test {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

... but clearly the C# is a lot more compact.

Basically, C#'s properties make for more readable code than having getter and setter methods as normal methods - but that's all they are, really. They're just used differently in code. The automatically implemented properties (as per the first snippet) make "trivial" properties simpler to express. In C# 6, you can write read-only automatically implemented properties too, which can be assigned to from the constructor but only the constructor.

Importantly though, you're still only making the *properties* part of the public API - not the fields. So if you later want to add some more logic (e.g. to have two properties derived from the same field, or something like that) you can do so without affecting either source or binary compatibility.

Comment: OH! That totally cleared things up. But does this mean I can't have a variable named string Name and string name (or maybe string _name)? Or is this something the compiler handles internally and I don't have to care about it.

Comment: @xElsa: I don't know what you mean. Conventionally the variables are camelCase with a lower-case name, and properties are PascalCased. You can't have two members with the same name (apart from overloaded methods).

Comment: Well, you said public string Name { get; set; } essentially creates a private variable called "name" and a public variable called "Name" so now we have two variables instead of one right? But I "technically" only created "Name" and "name" is hidden. So what if I went ahead and tried to declare "int name". Wouldn't that cause a conflict?

Comment: @xElsa: No, it creates a public *property* called `Name` and a *field* (instance variable) with a hidden name. Property != variable. They're very, very different. Now you *could* declare a field called `name` as well as an automatically implemented variable called `name`, but I'd strongly advise against it.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, okay. I didn't catch that. Now it makes sense. Thanks that cleared everything up.

Answer (score 2):

> and make them all public and use
>   private get; private set; to control accessibility?

No, not really. Let's have a look at this scenario:

```
private int _a;

public int A 
{
   get { return _a; } 
   private set { _a = value; }
}
```

So this field `_a` is encapsulated and cannot be accesed from anywhere except the same class. But `A` is a public property and it **is** inside the class so it can access `_a` field and work with it however its `set` accessor is private, so it cannot be accessed from outside of the class...

But to do something like this usually makes little sense :

```
private int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Ok, we created auto-implemented property to access private fields that it work with. But this property is `private` (used only inside the same class) and because it's auto-implemented it cannot contain any logic inside.

But if change it to :

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

It's more useful and the main difference from first example is that it creates backing field automatically. Though it still impossible to add some logic but it encapsulates `setter` method and it's a way of creating read-only properties (at least read-only outside of class).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use private variables only when you need to scope things internally to your class. They're obviously not visible from the outside.

The main reason for using `Properties` as they are known is when you want to add logic to your `gets` or `sets`. Say you want to validate a value before assignment, or you may want to delay load values and cache them in a get etc.

Here is a typical example when you'd want to use a property, over a simple value field:

```
private float latitude;
public float Latitude {
   get { return this.latitude; }
   set {
      if(value < -90 || value > 90) 
      { 
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid Latitude");
      }
      this.latitude = value;
   }
}
```

Now you could quite easily make the property private too, but you'd still be able to embed logic in there, obviously just not access it from outside. A singleton pattern is an example that springs off the top of my head.

You can also make the setting private for a variable. This allows you more flexibility to prevent people updating something they shouldn't, yet still give them access to the variable if need be.

```
private float latitude;
public float Latitude {
    get;
    private set;
}
```

Comment: So to clarify.. the design philosophy in Java was to make all members private (regardless of if they need to be accessed outside or not) and allow access through the get and set methods. Should I only use "properties" if I want to add additional logic to my get and sets and continue to use "getTest" and "setTest" and continue to declare my variables private or should I declare my variables as public now and use the properties to limit the scope?

Comment: You should always use properties. The C# {get; set;} is syntactic sugar for getters/setters in Java. It simplifies your basic getters and setters immensely, but still gives you full control over getting/setting when you need it.

Edit: "Immensely" might be a strong word, but it's a lot less annoying than adding 16 extra methods to every gosh dang class

Comment: @xElsa I'd keep the backing variable `latitude` private, but generally I'd expect a `Property` to be public. Note that you can have public gets, and private sets. Will update answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is true but I think it misses something important.

When you have:

```
class Test
{
    public int test { get; set; }
}
```

There is an unseen, private variable in your class called something like `_test`. This is not accessible outside of the class and is accessed with `get` and set with `set`. For the most part, you won't change those methods, but the option is there for you in the future if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

What you are using here are [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://Auto-Implemented%20Properties).

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create objects. When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's `get` and `set` accessors.

In other words, the two code blocks you posted are functionally the same.

The part that might not be obvious is that you also can declare either the getter or setter private, not necessarily the whole property, i.e.

```
public int test { get; private set; }
```

which would make it possible to get the value, but impossible to set the value from outside the class.

> However, for small classes or structs that just encapsulate a set of values (data) and have little or no behaviors, you should either make the objects immutable by declaring the set accessor as private (immutable to consumers) or by declaring only a get accessor (immutable everywhere except the constructor). For more information, see [How to: Implement a Lightweight Class with Auto-Implemented Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383979.aspx).